# multidimensional scatter plot with d3

Tags: d3.js, plot

I have a dataset which has 9 attributes out of which 2 are numerical and the rest are categorical. 
I wish to plot as many attributes as possible within a scatter plot matrix. D3 examples have shown me scatter plot matrices with a majority of numerical values. 
Are there any ways to plot multidimensional categorical data as scatter plots?

IF yes, are there any samples available on the wbe?

Comment: can you put a sample of your data set and what versus what you wish to plot a scatter chart.

Comment: It's called a [radar chart](http://bl.ocks.org/nbremer/6506614)

Comment: A typical scatterplot is two dimensional (x and y). You can add other dimensions, such as shape, color, and size, but you'd need to plot your categorical data somewhere in the x/y space for it to make any sense. For comparing categorical and continuous data, parallel coordinates are not a terrible option: https://syntagmatic.github.io/parallel-coordinates/

Comment: Here's a snapshot of my sample dataset: 
AgeAtTx,Ethnicity,Site,Tcategory,Nodal_Disease,ecog,Chemotherapy,Local_Therapy,Probability of Survival


65.93972603,white,supraglottic,T3,N+,0,no chemo,LP/RT alone,0.366190068

The first row indicates the names of the attributes and the second row indicates the actual values for one tuple. I.e the second row starts from the value 65.939